# What is the name of this letter $\mathcal{J}$?

Tags: deep-learning, notation, loss

What is the name of this letter $\mathcal{J}$ in the following deep learning equation? And what alphabet it is from?

$$\mathcal{J} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \mathcal{L}^{(i)}$$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to me that it belongs to https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an uppercase "J" from the math calligraphy alphabet, i.e. `\mathcal{J}` in latex.

$\mathcal{J}$